# How to get Json data using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have an issue to get Json data using PHP. I have an URL which contains JSON data like below.

```
 {  
       "Profile":{  
          "email":"abc@gmail.com",
       }
    }
```

When that URL is called i should get the `email` from the JSON data.I did like below to get the data.

```
$prof=json_decode($_REQUEST['Profile']);
```

But not getting any data.Here i need to get the email from that json value.Please help me.

Comment: How the URL looks like? @satya

Comment: is this your complete json ??

Comment: You have to decode the response first then access them.

Comment: @devpro : No,I have many data like this

Comment: Which data in your request _Profile_?

Comment: and what error r u getting?

Comment: @AnkiiG :its like this `http://example.com/api/profile.php?item=3&acn=1`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma after email id in the json.

Therefore, your json is incomplete.

If you remove it, you will get email.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
$json = '{  
       "Profile":{  
          "email":"abc@gmail.com"
       }
    }';
$arr = json_decode($json);
echo $arr->Profile->email;
?>
```

If you manage the page from where the json comes, you can take care of not adding this extra comma.

**EDIT:**

If you have the same format of elements and sub elements in JSON, following code will work:

```
<?php
$json = '{  
       "Profile":{  
          "email":"abc@gmail.com",
       }
    }';
$json = str_replace(' ', '', $json);
$json = str_replace('",', '"', $json);
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->Profile->email;
?>
```

What steps are followed:

1) Removed spaces

2) Replaced `",` with `"`.

3) Decoded json.

Comment: All JSON data are with the URL.I have to only fetch those.

Answer (score 2):

Properties of objects and the elements of arrays might be more objects or arrays.you can simply access their properties and members  using this syntax.**$this->object->element**

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$email = $data->Profile->email
print_r($email);
```

FOR get URL values you can try this:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($json_data["Profile"]['email']);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to remove the comma after the email, since it's invalid JSON. You can check the validity of your JSON from the following link...

http://jsonlint.com/

Then consider the following code segment...

```
$json = '{
    "Profile": {
        "email": "abc@gmail.com"
    }
}';
$result = json_decode ($json);

var_dump($result->Profile->email);
```

As per the given JSON, it contains the "Profile" object within "$result" object. So you can access your object property in the given way. So if you're still not sure how to do it, just assign the valid JSON to $json variable in the given code and keep the rest of the code as it is and it will work !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do that

```
$prof=json_decode($_REQUEST);
```

You will obtain an object in php. Then do that :

```
$prof->Profile->email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{"Profile":{"email":"abc@gmail.com"}}';
$arr = json_decode($string);
echo $arr->Profile->email;
```

Comment: Adding an explanation as to why this approach works would make your contribution more valuable for the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my example for describe view [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/yqw0-6y1i).

As per the documentation, you need to specify if you want an associative array instead of an object from `json_decode`, this would be the code:

```
json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

In case of you are working on php less then 5.2 you can use this resource.
[Using json_encode() and json_decode() in PHP4](http://techblog.willshouse.com/2009/06/12/using-json_encode-and-json_decode-in-php4/)